# Finding the correct settings for Lucene Spell Check

Tags: java, lucene, spell-checking

I have a spellchecker indexed on a list of cities, countries, names etc. extracted from a portion of Wikipedia. I am getting bad results for some simple queries,

> Crotia
>   => Croton,Crotty,Parotia
>
> Engerland
>   => Eggerland, Egerland, Wangerland
>
> Packistan
>   => Packington, Packing
>
> Roawn Atkinson
>   =>  John Atkinson, Colin Atkinson, Alan Atkinson, Rowan Atkinson

I am using the default spellchecker, something akin to [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/did-you-mean-feature-lucene-spell.html).

Any suggestions on how to improve the results? This looks terrible.

Comment: Can't give much meaningful information without more to go on.  For the last one, I would suspect you are trying to match a two-word term against single-word (tokenized) contents (in which case, any Atkinson will be an equally good match).  For the rest, are you sure the terms you are looking for are in your spell checker's dictionary?

Comment: Yes, that is true (maybe I should check per token). Terms like Eggerland etc. are in the dictionary.

Actually I fixed this using the directSpellChecker in Lucene, that is giving me better results!